# cannot upload csv file and get error C:\xampp\tmp\php9F4F.tmp

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, xampp

I'm working on a website that required me to create function to upload .csv file.
When upload the file, it says wrong format, and it display this message:

> C:\xampp\tmp\php9F4F.tmp

p/s:I already convert the excel file into .csv comma delimited format and still get error while uploading.

**What should I do to resolve the error and then get to upload the csv file into my database?**

stdreport.php : //im using the same code from import.php in here to connect it with database

```
<?php
$SQLSELECT = "SELECT stdCard, stdName, stdProgram, stdCourseDesc, stdCampus 
                FROM student 
                ORDER BY stdID 
                LIMIT 0,20";

$result_set =  mysql_query($SQLSELECT, $conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
?>
```

import.php

```
<?php 
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("dashboard",$conn) or die("could not connect database");

if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            //It wiil insert a row to our subject table from our csv file`
            $sql = "INSERT into student 
                            (`stdID`, `stdCard`, `stdName`, 
                            `stdOfficialEmail`,`stdEmail`, 
                            `stdContNum`,`stdCourseDesc`, `stdCampus`, 
                            `accessDate`) 
                    values('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]',
                            '$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]',
                            '$emapData[6]', '$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]',
                            '$emapData[9]')";

            //we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error
            $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            if(! $result ) {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                        window.location = \"stdreport.php\"
                    </script>";
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        //throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                window.location = \"stdreport.php\"
            </script>";

             //close of connection
            mysql_close($conn); 
         }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You are not uploading anything with that code. You're just reading a csv file and at the same time adding its values into database.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the excel file to CSV then there is two type of formate CSV UTF-8 (comma delimited ) and the second one is CSV (comma delimited ), use the second option I have also attached the screenshot.

[image]